# The servlet mapping "javax.ws.rs.core.Application" refers to a servlet that is not defined

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm attempting to configure a jax-rs service using only javax.ws.rs API and an anonymous servlet.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <display-name>com.whatever.rest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/www/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My web app deploys to TomEE just fine, my paths work great, everything's smooth... but Eclipse is giving me the error:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type The servlet mapping "javax.ws.rs.core.Application" refers to a servlet that is not defined  web.xml /whatever/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF Unknown Web Problem
```

How do I `define` this anonymous servlet without creating an implementing class so that Eclipse will shut up and the red icons in my IDE go away?

Answer (score 2):

You can activate JAX-RS implementing the `Application` and skipping the XML configuration, as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

this is something eclipse doesn't support (at least last time I checked) cause it is aligned on servlet specification and JAX-RS is not built in.